# WPF: Switching Views with DataTemplates - How to have view change its DataContext automatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, contentcontrol

Thanks in advance for any help I can get!  I'll jump right in!

Assume I have the following XAML.  I left out parts that wouldn't be needed to hopefully keep this easier to read.

The `TreeView` is populated in the MainWindow code behind by created an ObservableCollection of `MainViewModelBase`objects.  The Properties of those objects are based on a XML file read in at start by the main windows code being.

This makes the items of the `TreeView` of type `MainViewModelBase`.  From there I want to use the string "Type" property (which was read in from the XML) of the `SelectedItem` of the `Treeview` to display a UserControl on the right side of the screen.  Based  on TONs of googling, the below code uses DataTemplates to accomplish the view switches.

My question is this.  The UserControl that I want to populate needs to be be binded to another XML file, and the name of that XML file will be based on the string called Name stored in the `MainViewModelBase`.  The code below gets the new view to show up, but I can't figure out how to get the new Views DataContext to be set to the XML.  There must be some way though the content control to do this.  I think that when you use a DataTemplate to do the switch, the resulting view inherits the DataContext of the ViewModel type that "created" it.  But I think the DataContext isn't set until after the constructor of the view is done.  Thus I can't have the constructor of the view open the XML based on the string "name" of the MainViewModel.  Is there a way to have the DataContext updated after the fact?  Thanks!

Another note, there is lots of items in the `TreeView`, thus lots of XMLs.  I don't want to have all XMLs in memory at once, only when the view that needs it needs it.

Finally, I am new to WPF, so I apologize in advance if part of my above question are dumb or completely confusing.  I am asking them from the perspective of someone new to the technology.

Note:  I know I can bind the `TreeView` directly to the initial XML, and I may switch to that in the future, I'm not sure yet.  Most examples online were using ObservableCollections of VeiwModel objects, so it was easier to learn this way.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="BlankTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MainViewModelBase}">
        <View:BlankControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ParagraphTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MainViewModelBase}">
        <View:ParagraphControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MainViewModelBase}">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BlankTemplate}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Paragraph">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ParagraphTemplate}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>

    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TreeView Name="navigationPane" Grid.Column="0"/>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=navigationPane, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Googling, I found a great project on codeproject that describes how to use the view model idea to make a load on command treeview.  What I really liked about this was that it showed me how to use the INotifyPropertyChanged stuff to bind the isSelected property to something in the view model that could be used todo the XML loading etc.

I know this may seem basic to you WPF gurus out there, but this was so helpful in explaining to me how to really use the ViewModel pattern.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Answer (score 0):

After reading your post if I'm not wrong, you basically have a treeview on left hand side and on the basis of selection you want to populate some user control on right hand side. That's the crux of the requirement.

If above is the case what can be done is to bind the left and right side views to separate viewmodels. On selecting something from left hand side, you can pass the selection in the parameterized constructor of the right hand side view. Hence you'll have the input selected on LHS and can do processing on RHS

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I wasn't sure how you do the constructor part in the XAML (or at least not the code behind).  I'm still learning MVVM.  

See my answer to the whole question, I found a great example of working with the tree view.  It might be exactly what you were thinking about.

If anything, thanks for the help!